# MVVM: does change notification muddy the separation between model and viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Let's say I have a model which exposes a collection of objects which I will display and change in a GUI.

So we have Model exposing a collection of ModelItem.

The View binds to a ViewModel which exposes an ObservableCollection of ViewModelItem. ViewModelItem is the Viewmodel of ModelItem

The View contains a ListBox and a DataTemplate. the DataTemplate is for items of type ViewModelItem. The View DataContext points at an instance of ViewModel. The ListBox binds to the ObservableCollection.

I control all the code.

So far so simple. Question:

Is it acceptable to expose the collection on the Model as an ObservableCollection? Further, is it acceptable to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on Model and ModelItem?

My concern is I'm muddying the separation between model and viewmodel, but then common sense says, here's a mechanism for notifying changes to elements in my model, lets use it...

Just wanted to get some perspective from others.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to let the user manipulate your data from inside the view or do you just want to display it?

Comment: My personal experience is that MVVM must not be pushed to far. Stay pragmatic or you gonna over design the whole thing.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the data will be editable through the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** 
YES.  Use your notification interfaces on your model when you need to notify of changes.  Do not worry about muddying your code with this.  Be pragmatic.

**Long answer:** 
My philosophy goes like this:  When implementing MVVM, bind directly to model objects when there is nothing extra to do.  When you need something new (new behavior, properties the view will utilize, etc) then you wrap the model objects in ViewModel objects.  A ViewModel that does nothing but delegate data from the model is nothing but extra code.  The moment you need to do something to that data past what the model object gives you, you introduce the layer.

So, to extend my thoughts further on that, (and to answer your question more directly), there needs to be a way for the model to tell the ViewModel when something changes.  Often, model data is immutable so it doesn't need this notification mechanism, so it isn't necessary.  BUT, it is also often the case that the model DOES change.  When that happens, the model has two options: use a custom notification method (events, delegates, etc) or use `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

If you look at the namespace for `INotifyPropertyChanged`, it is in `System.ComponentModel` -- not the view -- so I prefer to use it in the model.  It is a well-known interface and you can use it to bind directly to your model from your view.  No need to implement anything different.

Taking this philosophy one step further, `ObservableCollection` is in `System.Collections.ObjectModel` -- also not view-specific -- and it implements `System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged` which also is not view-specific.  In other words, `ObservableCollection` was designed to be a collection that notifies its observers of changes.  If you have a model that needs to do that, then `ObservableCollection` is your tool.  It just happens to be convenient (not by accident, though) that WPF and Silverlight use these interfaces for data binding.

I guess this is a long-winded way of saying: "YES.  Use your notification interfaces on your model when you need to notify of changes.  Do not worry about muddying your code with this.  Be pragmatic."

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely acceptable to do both. I would even say it's *required* to do both. Your common sense abilities work just fine. :)

I would only add that if you don't need all the MVVM functionality for your `ModelItem`s, then you can cut some corners by exposing an `ObservableCollection<ModelItem>` instead of an `ObservableCollection<ViewModelItem>`, and modifying your `DataTemplate` to suit. This will save you quite a bit of "preparation" code, so weigh the pros and cons.

Comment: That's good to know. I'm not sure what's causing the sense of un-ease, I think I'm expecting something to be half baked or require dubious work arounds some where. Some sort of hidden gotcha's anyway. So far WPF has been pretty Gotcha free :)

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly acceptable to use change notification in the data model if the data model needs change notification.  It's also questionable to use change notification in the data model just because the UI needs change notification.

Generally, I design the data model as if there *were* no UI, and use the view model as an abstraction layer that hides the data model's implementation details from the UI.  On the other hand, in a dynamic application it can be the case that the need for change notification is pervasive enough that it just makes more sense to put it in the data model.

Comment: Actually this and DanDan's answers are interesting. I haven't provided a lot of detail because I'm after general guidance, but I think I was intimating that the view's job was to manage the representation AND updating of the model. Edit: Oops hit return. So in this case there's a closeness between the underlying model and the view. I would argue against DanDan that if my model implemented an interface which provided Observerable collections, any model implementing that interface could be interchangeable. That's as an example rather than a hard and fast rule.

Comment: One of the apps I'm developing has a very dynamic data model that's designed entirely in support of the UI.  In this case I've had no problems putting change notification into the model, since providing information to the UI is the model's primary purpose.  My guideline for model design in this case is not "would I design this differently if the UI didn't exist?" but "would I design this differently if the UI were WinForms?"

Answer (score 1):

No.  It's horrible.  Your model should not know how it is used. Giving it this knowledge defeats the object of MVVM.
The model should never know it is being used by WPF, winforms, a dos console, as a service or as a lib.  If you tell it this, you are going wrong.
It should also be framework independent, not minding if it's part of MVVM, MVC or MXXX!

Comment: I completely disagree as adding those elements to the data model is both pragmatic, and normal, they are NOT UI specific, nor are they even UI RELATED constructs.